# Unable to find element in WCF ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
   [OperationContract]
   DataTable GetADUserList(string strUserName, string strFirstName, string strLastName, string strEmail, string domain);
}
```

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS with the sample service contract above. The service web.config file settings are as below.

**Full WCF Web.config file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="notSecureBinding">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="SecureBinding">
                     <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc"
                      binding="customBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="notSecureBinding"
                      contract="ADSearcher.IService1"
                      name="notSecureBinding" />

            <endpoint address="http://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc"
                      binding="customBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
                      contract="ADSearcher.IService1"
                      name="SecureBinding" />
        </client>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

      </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And i'm trying to access the service programmatically as below.

```
  EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc");
  IService1 ADUser = new ChannelFactory<IService1>("notSecureBinding", endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
```

The above code is throwing the error below

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'notSecureBinding' and contract 'ADSearcher.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element

I can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong here or is there a better alternative to access this service programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

In your endpoint, you are specifying a contract of type `Data.GetData`.  The contract is of type `IService1`, and by default, the contract name should be the typename of the service interface.

If you really want your `IService` to be referred to as `Data.GetData`, you can specify the identifying name via the `ServiceContractAttribute`:

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "Data.GetData")]
public interface IService1
{
   [OperationContract]
   DataTable GetADUserList(string strUserName, string strFirstName, string strLastName, string strEmail, string domain);
}
```

Comment: i have followed both your answer and that of Tom Redfern  but i still can't get this to work (i have updated my original questions' <binding> and <client> sections to match what i currently have, please CHECK). Could i be pointing to a wrong web.config file?. The WCF dll is placed in the WCF service website's bin folder. I then added a reference to this same WCF dll to my MVC application so i can access contract of type IService1, is this the correct way of doing it. I can successfully get to the service from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'customBinding'....in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section

This is because you are defining two client endpoints in your config file. And they are named:

- notSecureBinding, and
- SecureBinding

So the error message is correct, there is no endpoint element with name "customBinding".

I think you need to do this:

```
IService1 ADUser = new ChannelFactory<IService1>("<either of the two bindings you defined>").CreateChannel();
```

> Do i need to configure any thing related to WCF in the ASP.NET MVC
>   application's web.config file?

OK so now I understand. You are hosting the WCF service in your ASP.NET website. And you're trying to call it from somewhere else I assume?

You definitely need to define a `<system.serviceModel />` section in your web.config, which will tell IIS how to host your service.

At the moment, the configuration you gave posted above defines to *client* endpoints. These do not reference service endpoints, but rather is client config designed to allow you to call services. The hint is in the name of the section node: `<client />`. To define service endpoints that you wish to expose you need to put your endpoint config in a `<service />` section. In your case it may only be necessary to change the "client" to "service" to make it all work.

The code which is calling the service may or may not need client configuration in the app.config file. You say you are calling it programatically (although without seeing your full client code I don't know that you are doing enough to satisfy the WCF client call stack), in which case you don't need client config. I hope this makes things clearer for you.

Comment: changing "customeBinding" to either "notSecureBinding" or "SecureBinding" still gives me the same error.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior - See Andrew Shepherd answer. You actually had two problems - I have addressed one and andrew the other. You basically need to change the contract value in your client endpoint config to equal the fully qualified name of the type defined as your service definition (in your case myNamespace.IService1)

Comment: i have followed both your answer and that of Andrew Shepherd answer but i still can't get this to work (i have updated my original questions' <binding> and <client> sections to match what i currently have, please CHECK). Could i be pointing to a wrong web.config file?. The WCF dll is placed in the WCF service website's bin folder. I then added a reference to this same WCF dll to my MVC application so i can access contract of type IService1, is this the correct way of doing it. I can successfully get to the service from the browser.

Comment: IService1 needs to be fully qualified with the namespace.

Comment: i still get the same error even after fully qualifying IService1 with the namespace.

Comment: Do i need to configure any thing related to WCF in the ASP.NET MVC application's web.config file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78218/discussion-between-sql-net-warrior-and-tom-redfern).

Comment: Quote "OK so now I understand. You are hosting the WCF service in your ASP.NET website. And you're trying to call it from somewhere else I assume?" ...............No, its the opposite. I'm hosting the service in its own independent website and i'm trying to call the service from my ASP.NET MVC application. Your edit however gives me a hint, it looks like i have to also define a <service /> section in the WCF Web.config file because currently, the <service /> section isn't defined there, is this right. I'm going to update my original question with the WCF websites full  web.config file.

Comment: Yes you are correct. If you're hosting a service then you need to define a `<service />` section of the config file